# In Java, is there a way to save the boolean variable here so that it persists?

Tags: java

I want to create a boolean variable that simply tells the user whether this is the first time running the class, or it's the second(or `nth` time afterwards) .  How would I do this?

```
public class boolTest {

  static boolean dirty;


   public static void main (String[] args) {

    dirty = false;

    if (!dirty) {
          System.out.println("First time running.");      
          dirty = true;
          System.out.println("Now it's true.");
     } 
     else 
      {
      System.out.println("this is already true.");

       }

}
}
```

The problem is that , it's always saying "First time running" -

> C:\Java_Scratch>java boolTest First time running. Now it's true.
>
> C:\Java_Scratch>java boolTest First time running. Now it's true.

Comment: Uh, you'll need to persist that state externally. The lifetime of a variable is at most tied to the lifetime of the application.

Comment: As far as the program is concerned, it's the first time it has run.

Comment: @Whymarrh-  so, to  persist externally we would write to text file I'm guessin. Ok thanks

Comment: just curious, why do need to do that ? what's your end goal ?

Comment: @niceman -  this is part of a program ( call it 'SuperParent.java`  )  , which will be monitoring a simple log file.  We want to differentiate between the first time a log file has been written to, versus every other time.  Because if it's the first time, no need to count the lines in it - but otherwise, we will count lines   ( still fleshing out the idea, but that's gist of it )

Comment: @Coffee I don't think storing a boolean value is the best choice, there are IO API's in java and there must be a function to see if file is empty, I suggest you learn java.io package if you don't know it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to persist that information into some file on the disc manually. Actually, you don't even need to persist it *into* a file, but just *as* a file. (The pure existence of the file is enough information in this case).

For instance like this:

```
File checkFile = new File(".checkfile");
if(!checkFile.exists() || !checkFile.isFile()){
   // file does not exist, so this is the first time running the program.
   // create the file so that we know we have already run the next time
   Files.createFile(checkFile.toPath());
} else {
  // This file exists, we already ran the program previously
}
```

Answer (score 6):

a static field in a class is shared across all instances of a class throughout your *program's runtime*. Once your program stopped and re-executed, everything that is stored on the heap is gone, regardless if it's static or not.

to do what you want, you need either to store it to a file, or an environment variable or some external storage, it can't be on the program's memory

Answer (score 0):

You need to write it to a file, then read that file the next time.  Memory (RAM) is never persistent.  Files on disk are.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JPA (Java Persistence API)

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/tech/persistence-jsp-140049.html

Comment: Well the only other way would be to store it in a file so this is somthing different becuase that solution is too obvious.

Comment: @Coffee this is a server-side programming thing related to web development and persistent connections which requires Java EE

Answer (score 0):

The way I understand your question, you want the if part (in your example) run only once.
For example:

- Your run this code today -> "First time running. Now it's true."
- Turn of your computer
- The next day you run that code again -> "this is already true."

If thats the case you have to store the "dirty" information in a file or a database.